# How to change a certain point on a scatterplot in Plotly a different colour to rest of data

Tags: r, plotly

[image]

I am using Plotly to plot a scatterplot of GWAS data and want to highlight a certain point a different colour to the rest of the data. I have tried multiple times but unable to find away around this in Plotly. Any advice would be great please.

input data looks like this:

[image: input data]

```
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data=data_1, x = ~BP, y = ~log, name = "data",  mode = "markers", type = "scatter",
                         y = c(117300000, 117900000), marker = list(size = 8, color = '#d62728'), 
                         x = c(117558703), y = c(19.75696195), marker = list(color = 'blue',size = 8), type = "scatter")
fig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to create a variable to identify that specific point. I created sample data here and assigned a colour variable equal to 1 for the point I want in another color.

```
df = tibble(bp = round(rnorm(10,5,2),2),
            log = round(rnorm(10,6,1.5),2))
df$colour <- as.factor(ifelse(df$bp == 4.41,1 ,0))
fig <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~bp, y = ~log, group_by = ~colour,marker = list(color = factor(df$colour,labels=c("red","purple"))))  %>%
add_trace(data = df, x = ~bp, y = ~log, mode = 'markers', type = 'scatter')
fig
```

[Link to plot produced by this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7guSP.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have tried to recreate with my data. But I get error cannot find function add_trace? Is this through a different package? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to add an indicator variable to your data to indicate which points you want to highlight. This variable could then be mapped on the `color` attribute. The colors could then be set via the `colors` attribute.

Using a minimal reproducible example base on `mtcars`:

```
library(plotly)

data_1 <- mtcars
data_1$highlight <- row.names(data_1) %in% c("Honda Civic", "Porsche 914-2")

plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(
    data = data_1, x = ~hp, y = ~mpg, color = ~highlight,
    mode = "markers", type = "scatter",
    marker = list(size = 8), colors = c("#d62728", "blue")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, makes sense. I have tried to recreate with my data though. But I get error cannot find function add_trace? Is this through a different package? Thank you! –

Comment: Hej Holly. No. `add_trace` is from the `plotly` package. See your code snippet.

Comment: Thank you - for some reason wasnt working. Reinstalled and now working! Thank you for your help! This works well

Comment: Hi Stefan, my image looks great now - thank you. Quick question re plotly if you are able to help? Is here a way to also fade the red dots in your example above? Just so the blue ones look even more prominent? It just might make my image look even more powerful? Thank you so much for your help!